# Is it possible to use Blazor withour Razor just a way to use C# logic from .NET Standard library?

Tags: blazor

I want to use the logic implemented in a .NET Standard library in a web page.

For this, I'd like to call some public static C# methods from JavaScript.

Can I do this with Blazor but without using Razor? If yes, how exactly?

Can I just compile to web assembly without even using Blazor?

Comment: Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0. You can call blazor methods from JS which in turn calls your mentioned library if that is what you want.

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't clear. I edited my question

Comment: I just want to use C# in web browser by WebAssembly. I don't really need Blazor, I just want to use the logic I have implemnted in a .NET Standard library by calling it from JS

Comment: With Blazor you don't really need JS, cause you can use C# on both ends (client as well as the server side) - this is the main benefit of Blazor: JS is only required for things not yet ported to Blazor

Comment: "I just want to use C# in web browser by WebAssembly. I don't really need Blazor" is a bit of a contradiction. If you want Wasm code, and you want to write it in C#, then use Blazor, as that's exactly what it was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/use-net-7-from-any-javascript-app-in-net-7/) shows .NET on WebAssembly without using Blazor comes with .NET 7.